# How can EditText include a check box

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to make a note app and every note can include `Checkbox`s depending on the user's tasks. The question is how can I inject the `EditText` with a `CheckBox` once a button is clicked?. I searched for libraries on GitHub but I could not find something that satisfies me or something that can be customizable. Then I tried to make my custom editor that inherits from `AppCompatEditText`, and after making that class I looked at it and said how the f I am going to include that checkBox

The same as in the middle green image:

[image]

Comment: That’s just a check box next to an EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a layout which contains checkbox and edittext, and use the layout when the user adds the note. Simple if statement is enough to make this workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what I am not getting is how to insert that layout (checkbox aligned with edit text ) after a few lines were typed. like in the red image, the user has typed a few lines then the check box is added in the middle of the text. did you get what I am trying to say?

Comment: It is a more of a logical change than the development. Allow user to enter text then provide a small option like a buton to add todo list. if he clicks todo list button, then open the edittext with checkbox